# SPARQL - fetching data from dbpedia and wikidata

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

How can i fetch result from both wikidata and dbpedia

```
SELECT ?film 
WHERE { 
 ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424;
       wdt:P915 wd:Q506250.                    
}
```

Comment: "Expecting help from expert" is a bad premise -- but might just be a language issue. If you have a well described problem description, an expert might volunteer their incredibly valuable time, free of charge --
 or not... "doesn't work" in what way? What did you expect? What did you get instead? Where's the gap? Why are you involving two separate surfaces, when, on the surface, it would seem that one would do?

Comment: @Bikash You changed the whole query ... and now? As I said, you have to figure out on which resource or literal you could map both datasets. I hope you understand the original problem

Answer (score 1):

This can't work because DBpedia and Wikidata use different URIs for identifying resources. This should be quite obvious if you look at the results when simply retrieving actors from both datasets.